# PHP running multiple instance issue

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

```
 5877 pts/1    S      0:00 php cron_run.php
 5879 pts/1    S      0:00 sh -c /usr/bin/php /srv/www/videofix.d.com/public_html/v/complete.php
 5880 pts/1    S      0:00 /usr/bin/php /srv/www/videofix.d.com/public_html/v/complete.php
 5884 pts/1    S      0:00 sh -c php 2.php 4584.2
 5885 pts/1    S      0:01 php 2.php 4584.2
```

I tried to ps ax and saw that my cron_run.php

which execute complete.php

but there seems to be 2 instances running.

```
1 is with sh -c
1 is without
```

Is it 2 instances or actually 1 instance.

```
How do i modify my code so it only run one instance at a time
```

This is my cron run file

```
<?php
while(1<2)
{
//run every 2 minutes

shell_exec("/usr/bin/php /srv/www/videofix.d.com/public_html/v/complete.php");

sleep(120);
}
?>
```

Running in endless loop, but without the sh -c, so there only 1 /usr/bin

**Thanks for helping**

Comment: Because `sh`  calls `/usr/bin/php`  you see two. If you run `ps axf` you can see better what's going on: so there' no real problem: there's 1 complete.php job running. Why do you call `shell_exec` instead of `include`ing it?

Comment: `sh -c php` isn't PHP itself. It's the (SH)ell created by your `shell_exec()` call.

Comment: Additionally, I would consider reviewing what `complete.php` does, and if it can be ported to a shell script instead.

Comment: If you can adjust to use crontab instead of php, please do.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to remove the extra process by changing the shell_exec line to:

```
shell_exec("exec /usr/bin/php /srv/www/videofix.d.com/public_html/v/complete.php");
```

This makes the executed shell replace itself with the command rather than forking a new process for it.  (This trick works for me under Linux, under OSX and FreeBSD no extra shell lingers.)